# SSL/TLS Issues on IE9

Tags: asp.net, ssl

I have an asp.net site on a secured site.  It would not allow me to view it.  It recommended changing the SSL and TLS settings in the advanced tab of tool options.  This worked.  Although I don't want a workaround to make the site work as it would be annoying for everyone that goes to the site in IE would have to apply this workaround.  Is there something on the server I need to set or in .net?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly did you modify?

Comment: How exactly did you change the SSL/TLS settings in your browser to make it work? We need to know the actual problem you are having that caused you to change your settings in the first place.

Comment: I enabled all of the ssl and tls security settings.  Use ssl 2.0, use ssl 3.0, use tls 1.0, use tls 1.1, use tls 1.2.  I didn't modify anything and to my knowledge nobody else has.  This may have been an issue existing for some time and just found because it works fine in chrome and firefox but by default I think ssl2 and tls 1.0 are checked.

Comment: Though it seems the ssl setting didn't make a difference it was the tls.  I just tried it and just going up to 1.1 fixed it.

Comment: What is the reason you are using such an old browser? Do you still use Firefox 2.0 and Chrome 1.0, too?

Answer (score 1):

Since the [POODLE attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE) SSL 3.0 is considered insecure, and many websites already disabled it.

Now, according to  [this table on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Web_browsers) TLS 1.1 and 1.2 are supported in IE9, but disabled by default.  The fact that you actually had to enable TLS 1.1 seems to suggest that the website operator also disabled TLS 1.0.

Best remedy is to update that old browser ([IE9 is 6.5 years old](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9)) or just once fully enable TLS.  The only reason they left it disabled as installed is probably just compatibility with some long-forgotten legacy product of them anyways.

---

Just recently it was discovered that the [POODLE can also bite TLS](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2014/12/08/poodle-bites-tls), but SSL Labs already has a test for it so you can quickly verify if your site is immune.